# Making variable optional in underscore.js template

Tags: javascript, templates, underscore.js

I have this code:

```
_.templateSettings = {interpolate : /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g};

var _d = _.template($('#_d').html());

$.get('/foo', function(data) {
    $('#output').html(_d(data));
});
```

and in HTML:

```
<div id="_d">
    {{name}} {{phone}}
</div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

`/foo` returns something like `{"name":"joe","phone":"12345"}`, but sometimes it doesn't have `phone` thus simply returns `{"name":"joe"}`, which will choke template evaluation thus nothing gets printed in `output`. How do I make a variable optional?

**EDIT:** `/foo` is beyond my control

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `||` operator is useful for this sort of thing:

```
$.get('/foo', function(data) {
    data.phone = data.phone || "";
    $('#output').html(_d(data));
});
```

But since you're already using Underscore, you can use the [`_.defaults`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#defaults) function. This approach is particularly useful for providing defaults for multiple fields:

```
$.get('/foo', function(data) {
    _.defaults(data, {name : 'joe', phone : ''});
    $('#output').html(_d(data));
});
```

Answer (score 5):

I liked @namuol solution, another thing that we could do is set the defaults hash at the model extends

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        "foo": "I",
        "bar": "love",
        "yeah": "sara"
    }
});
```

Just another option.

Answer (score 3):

You can have an html

```
<div id="d">
    {{data.name}} {{data.phone}}
</div>
```

Use the template as below to avoid undefined variable issue for `phone`

```
_.templateSettings = {
  interpolate : /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g
};

var template = _.template($('#d').html());
var jsonResponse = {"name":"Jeo"}; // phone is missing
var result = template({"data":jsonResponse});
```

Answer (score 1):

A practical solution would be to include `phone` in the object, but with an empty value:

```
{"name":"joe","phone":""}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some good answers above, but you can use [`_.partial`](http://underscorejs.org/#partial) to get a single function that applies a template with defaults:

```
foobarTemplate = _.template('<%=foo%><%=bar%>')
barPrefilled = _.partial(_.defaults, _, {bar:'def'})
foobarTemplate(barPrefilled({foo:'abc'}))
//  "abcdef"
foobarTemplateWithDefaults = function (data) {return foobarTemplate(barPrefilled(data));}
foobarTemplateWithDefaults({foo:'wat'})
//  "watdef"
foobarTemplateWithDefaults({foo:'foo', bar:'bar'})
//  "foobar"
```

Answer (score 1):

And then there is the obvious: Put this in the top of your template:

```
<%
  if (typeof(phone) === "undefined") {
    phone = "";
  }
%>
```

Working snippet:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#result').html(
    _.template(
      $('#template').html(), {
        interpolate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g
      }
    )({
      foo: 23,
      // No value for bar
      // bar: 11,
    },)
  )
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="x-template" id="template">
<%
  if (typeof(bar) === "undefined") {
    bar = "default";
  }
%>
This is {{ foo }} and {{ bar }}
</script>

<div id="result"></div>
```

(also as [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pmorch/72svhfra/))